# Jakarta ConcurrentModificationException or IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf, primefaces, mojarra

Hello i get a error when im pressing a button, but not always, sometimes its a different error, sometimes its working fine. Can someome explain me what is the problem? And how to fix this?

Button :

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="old" update="editnotizForm" oncomplete="PF('editnotizDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-assignment" disabled="#{b.id le 0 || b.typ eq 'P'}" rendered="#{b.typ ne 'P'}"
        style="#{b.getNotizen().isEmpty() ? 'background-color:gray;':'background-color:green;'};width:23px;height:23px;border:none">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{b}" target="#{psbBean.aktiv}" />
        <f:ajax />
</p:commandButton>
```

error:

```
10:43:33.081 [http-bio-8080-exec-7] FATAL pdp.jsf.exception.PrimeExceptionHandler - Index: 2, Size: 1
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.findChildByTagId(ComponentSupport.java:269) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.findChild(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:504) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:121) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:153) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:52) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:46) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:271) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:330) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:309) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:162) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:84) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:179) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:182) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:52) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:46) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:120) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:358) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:266) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.restoreView(OmniViewHandler.java:113) ~[omnifaces-3.13.4.jar:3.13.4]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:101) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:181) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76) [jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110) [jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177) [jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707) [jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451) [jakarta.faces-2.3.14.jar:2.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.primefaces.showcase.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:40) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239) [javamelody-core-1.88.0.jar:1.88.0]
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215) [javamelody-core-1.88.0.jar:1.88.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) [log4j-web-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.76]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.76]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.76]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_211]
```

Looking like a error from jakarta faces. I tried a newer version from jakarta (2.3.17) but im getting a other error

```
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
 at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1456) ~[?:1.8.0]
 at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1490) ~[?:1.8.0]
 at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:1488) ~[?:1.8.0]
 at java.util.HashMap.putMapEntries(HashMap.java:523) ~[?:1.8.0]
 at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:796) ~[?:1.8.0]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addAllDescendantMarkIds(ComponentSupport.java:289) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addToDescendantMarkIdCache(ComponentSupport.java:268) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2288) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$ChildrenList.add(UIComponentBase.java:2257) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentSupport.addComponent(ComponentSupport.java:533) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:330) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.addComponentToView(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:313) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:198) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:111) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:182) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:55) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:52) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:46) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:127) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:328) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:78) ~[jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76) [jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199) [jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708) [jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451) [jakarta.faces-2.3.17.jar:2.3.17]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.primefaces.showcase.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:40) [CharacterEncodingFilter.class:?]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239) [javamelody-core-1.88.0.jar:1.88.0]
 at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215) [javamelody-core-1.88.0.jar:1.88.0]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) [log4j-web-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:607) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.CrawlerSessionManagerValve.invoke(CrawlerSessionManagerValve.java:180) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) [catalina.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.76]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.76]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160) [?:1.8.0]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:1.8.0]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.76]
```

Comment: Perhaps caused by `<f:ajax/>` which is not needed for `p:commandButton` as commandButton by default performs ajax requests

Comment: ok removing `<f:ajax/>` stops producing the first error but the second error will still occure sometimes.

Comment: Try Mojarra 2.3.18 you upgraded to 2.3.17 but not the latest version 2.3.18

Comment: I also see the "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.faces.ComponentSupport.addAllDescendantMarkIds(ComponentSupport.java:343)" with jakarta.faces-4.0.2.jar